# Oven causing a circuit breaker to trip

Tags: circuit-breaker, oven

About 3 or four weeks ago, water was spilled onto the stove and ran into the burners. There was a pop from one of the burners and the oven went out. Breaker had tripped.
At first, I was able to reset the breaker, but then it tripped a short time later. Had a Whirlpool authorized repairman take a look at the 25 to 30-year-old oven. Every wire on the stove/oven was fine. Since it seemed to be working when he left, he thought it just needed to dry out from getting wet. After he left, everything worked fine for a day or two, and then we got the same pop from the burner, and now it tripped again and won't reset unless I unplug the oven. As the repairman did, I unplugged the oven and the breaker is on now working. So I presume the breaker is fine. The line with the breaker has another outlet with only a phone plugged in. The only other thing on the circuit with the oven is an overhead light for the stove. With the oven currently unplugged, both are working fine.
Thanks for any help.

The oven is a super capacity 465. It has electric starter but then runs off gas. A contractor used to live in the house about 5 years before we moved in. We've been here since 2006. He expanded and renovated the kitchen himself about 25 or 30 years ago. My in-laws have lived next door since the 1970s, that is why I know about the renovations. I knew that it should be on a breaker by itself, but we've found other questionable wiring in various parts of the house. It's a 20 amp breaker. I haven't seen any kind of a test breaker. I would presume it would be by the breaker.

Comment: What size is the breaker for the stove/oven?  It is unusual for any other circuits to be on the oven circuit.  Does the breaker have a test button?  If the breaker keeps tripping, there is something wrong with the oven.

Comment: Is this a gas range????

Comment: The oven is a super capacity 465. It has electric for it to heat up but then runs off gas. A contractor used to live in the house about 5 years before we moved in. We've been here since 2006. He expanded and renovated the kitchen himself about 25 or 30 years ago. My in-laws have lived next door since the 1970s, that is why I know about the renovations. I knew that it should be on a breaker by itself, but we've found other questionable wiring in various parts of the house. It's a 20 amp breaker. I haven't seen any kind of a test breaker. I would presume it would be by the breaker.

Comment: Does the breaker in question have a TEST button on it?

Comment: No, there is no test button on the breaker

Comment: Just to be sure, unplug the phone & light, plug in the oven & see if the breaker trips. Honestly, sounds like some sort of short in the internal wiring in the oven controls that's causing the breaker trip.